# How to calculate thickness of an object in PNG file using PHP GD library

Tags: php, image-processing, png, gd, php-gd

I have a PNG frame and I want to know its thickness. I am able to calculate the width/height of the image itself.

```
$frame = imagecreatefrompng('frame.png');
// get frame dimentions
$frame_width = imagesx($frame);
$frame_height = imagesy($frame);
```

But can't figure out a way to calculate thickness of frame, please see image below so see what I mean.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the last answer it shows that there's no objects in a raster image file. However, you can do it by searching the first occurrence of transparent colour and the first occurrence of the  non-transparent colour and calculate the distance of them (assumes that your image's blank area are all transparent).

Example code:

```
<?php
$img = imagecreatefrompng('./frame.png');//open the image
$w = imagesx($img);//the width
$h = imagesy($img);//the height

$nonTransparentPos = null;//the first non-transparent pixel's position
$transparentPos = null;//the first transparent pixel's position

//loop through each pixel
for($x = 0; $x < $w; $x++){
   for($y = 0; $y < $h; $y++){
        $color = imagecolorsforindex($img,imagecolorat($img,$x,$y));
        if($color['alpha'] < 127 && $nonTransparentPos === null){
            $nonTransparentPos = array($x,$y);
        }
        if($color['alpha'] === 127 && $transparentPos === null){
            $transparentPos = array($x,$y);
        }
   }
   //leave the loop if we have finished finding the two values.
   if($transparentPos !== null && $nonTransparentPos !== null){
        break;
   }
}
$length = $transparentPos[0]-$nonTransparentPos[0];//calculate the two point's x-axis distance
echo $length;
?>
```

Comment: $color = imagecolorsforindex($img,imagecolorat($image,$x,$y)); you referred a variable $image that is not declared and after replacing $image with $img the $length is getting same value for any input image.

Comment: Are you sure that the input image's blank areas are transparent?

Comment: Still doesn't work. See this frame (http://i.imgur.com/A6tSPhI.png) , its border width is 35px but your script shows 44.2px

Comment: @TahirYasin I figured out the problem. The script finds the distance from the diagonals. Now the script is really fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any objects in a PNG file. You can only get a color (with a transparency) by coordinates with [`imagecolorat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php) & [`imagecolorsforindex()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorsforindex.php).

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you guide me how can I measure the thickness of colored area?

Comment: It depends on the shape of your images. If they are all like in the example, just search the first, where `imagecolorat($image, $i, $i) == $backgroundColorIndex`